# Ionic plugin ThemeableBrowser offset issue on iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic3, inappbrowser

I am using ThemeableBrowser plugin

> ```
> cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser 0.2.17 "ThemeableBrowser"
> ```

in my Ionic 3 project. In all of the devices it works fine, recently i tried to update the app to display correctly on iPhone X , by following the official ios11 checklist - https://blog.ionicframework.com/ios-11-checklist/

All the issues i had were resolved, apart from the ThemeableBrowser, which opens pages with an negative offset. I tried using insertCss method of themeable browser as suggested  [HERE](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser/issues/163) , but this didn't work either.

This is initial state of the page when it opens:

[image]

Is there any other possible workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this issue by editing CDVThemableBrowser.m - there is an obvious bug for all iOS devices, it's just more obvious on iPhone X as it has bigger status bar. The rePositionViews , which set the position of webview doesn't add the statusBar height to it's Y position

I changed:

```
- (void) rePositionViews {
  CGFloat toolbarHeight = [self getFloatFromDict:_browserOptions.toolbar withKey:kThemeableBrowserPropHeight withDefault:TOOLBAR_DEF_HEIGHT];
  CGFloat webviewOffset = _browserOptions.fullscreen ? 0.0 : toolbarHeight;`
```

To:

```
- (void) rePositionViews {
  CGFloat toolbarHeight = [self getFloatFromDict:_browserOptions.toolbar withKey:kThemeableBrowserPropHeight withDefault:TOOLBAR_DEF_HEIGHT];
  CGFloat statusBarOffset = [self getStatusBarOffset];
  CGFloat webviewOffset = _browserOptions.fullscreen ? 0.0 : toolbarHeight + statusBarOffset;`
```

This solves the problem with the content offset

Comment: Nice answer! I'd be great if you could submit a PR in the repo to fix this in the next versions of the plugin :)

Comment: Thank you @sebaferreras , i created a PR here https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser/pull/170 , but there's not much activity on that repo for quite some time..

Comment: Wonderful answer! That resolved my issue in iPad device.